# PhD application cover letter closing formula(e)

Tags: phd, application-cover-letter

A friend has asked me to proofread their cover letter and CV for applying to a PhD position. I've done such proofreading when it was about more-or-less unskilled labour, or for friends who'd done a Bachelor's or Master's degree and were applying somewhere at some company. Never for a PhD, and I'm generally wondering what differences there are.

Specifically, the cover letter has the "thank you for your consideration" phrase at the end, followed by an "appreciate the opportunity to meet" phrase. A PhD is not a very common thing, so my question is: how appropriate (or not) is it to use such omnipresent formulae at the end of a cover letter seeking admission to one?

Comment: It might depend on how the phrase harmonizes or resonates with the rest of the letter.

Comment: I doubt it matters. Readers will see a wide variety of these and pass over them with little thought.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter. I'd probably suggest editing it to just one of those phrases, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Would you consider working Buffy's and TLDR's arguments into your answer? I feel both are valid and it'd make the answer a little more rounded.